# converting bytes to a string C#

Tags: c#

I want to convert a binary file to a string which could be then converted back to the binary file.
I tried this:

```
byte[] byteArray = File.ReadAllBytes(@"D:\pic.png");
for (int i = 0; i < byteArray.Length; i++)
{
    textBox1.Text += (char)byteArray[i];
}
```

but it's too slow, it takes about 20 seconds to convert 5KB on i5 CPU.
I noticed that notepad does the same in much less time.
Any ideas on how to do it?

Thanks

Answer (score 16, accepted):

If you want to be able to convert back to binary without losing any information, you shouldn't be doing this sort of thing at all - you should use base64 encoding or something similar:

```
textBox1.Text = Convert.ToBase64String(byteArray);
```

You can then convert back using `byte[] data = Convert.FromBase64String(text);`. The important thing is that base64 converts arbitrary binary data to known ASCII text; all byte sequences are valid, all can be round-tripped, and as it only requires ASCII it's friendly to many transports.

There are *four* important things to take away here:

- Don't treat arbitrary binary data as if it were valid text in a particular encoding. Phil Haack [wrote about this in a blog post recently](http://haacked.com/archive/2012/01/30/hazards-of-converting-binary-data-to-a-string.aspx), in response to some of my SO answers.
- [Don't perform string concatenation in a loop](http://www.yoda.arachsys.com/csharp/stringbuilder.html); use a `StringBuilder` if you want to create one final string out of lots of bits, and you don't know how many bits in advance
- Don't use UI properties in a loop unnecessarily - even if the previous steps were okay, it would have been better to construct the string with a loop and then do a *single* assignment to the `Text` property
- Learn about [`System.Text.Encoding`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.text.encoding.aspx) for the situation where you really *have* got encoded text; `Encoding.UTF8.GetString(byteArray)` would have been appropriate *if* this had been UTF-8-encoded data, for example

Comment: @Brad: because you can then use `Convert.FromBase64String` to get it back again later...

Comment: So the idea is then just use the same encoding and the Base 64 is the most generic in comparsion to UTF8, 16, etc..?

Comment: @Brad: They're not the same thing. `Encoding.UTF8` etc are used to represent arbitrary *text* as bytes... Base64 is used to represent arbitrary *binary* data as text.